# How to enable bitnami/redis-cluster logs deployed using helm?

Tags: redis, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, redis-cluster

I have done bitnami redis-cluster deployment using helm chart. I have followed below link for redis-cluster deployment-

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster

I wanted to enable redis logs, but not sure how to do it, as in the current bitnami redis image configuration file located at /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/redis.conf having parameter value logfile:"" as empty strings.

Please let me is there any ways to enable a redis server logs on each pod??

Comment: Currently, the logs should output to stdout, wouldn't that work for you? Could you explain the use case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use helm `--set` flag to overwrite the default values in the `redis.conf` file.

```
// Add your custom configurations 
$ export CUSTOM_CONFIG="logfile /data/logs/file.log"

// Apply those while installing 
$ helm install redis bitnami/redis-cluster --set redis.configmap=$CUSTOM_CONFIG
```

You can check it from inside the pod:

```
$ kubectl exec -it redis-redis-cluster-0 -- cat /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/redis.conf
.
.
.
logfile /data/logs/file.log
```

Comment: getting error with this change.. Unexpected arguments : /opt/bitnami/redis/logs/redis.log  which I am passing through CUSTOM_CONFIG.

Comment: @andy you need to provide a valid directory, if your PVC is mounted on `/data`, you can try with a subpath under it.

Comment: For deployment using this command:- helm install redis bitnami/redis-cluster --set redis.configmap=$CUSTOM_CONFIG --values values-production.yaml -n  bitnami-redis                                                                                         getting error: expected at most two arguments, unexpected arguments :/bitnami/redis/data/redis.log                                       i am doing dynamic binding for pvc, and by default data path will mount to /bitnami/redis/data               so after addition of CUSTOM_CONFIG Parameter the deployment itself is giving error.Any idea on this?